# swiftUI retrieving image from json

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried hard to retrieve the image with the title . title is working perfectly but image doesn't appear . the code is ( I am working on apple tutorial of swiftui )

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark : Landmark
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            landmark.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50,height: 50)
            Text(landmark.name)
            Spacer()
    }
}
}
struct LandmarkRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmarkData[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add

```
HStack{
            Image(landmark.imageName)//imagename is the name of the image as given in the landmark model object
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50,height: 50)
            Text(landmark.name)
            Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks brother for your reply. you are right the name of the image is imageName in the json , but I find the solution that I put all the image in Resource folder instead of assets folder.